# How to perform segue acording to the indexPath.row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am parsing a JSON file, and displaying the JSON data in a `UITableView`. I am using `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;` to pass the values to the other ViewController. Now I need to pass values acording to the `indexPath.row`, like

```
NSDictionary *dict;
dict = [application objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But I dont know how I can do this in the prepearForSegue methode. I tryed to asign the `indexPath.row` from `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`, but the value is asigned after the prepearForSgue methode.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What does "according to the indexPath.row" mean? You're displaying data from JSON in a table view.  Are you saying that the user clicks a row in a table view and that loads another view controller, or are you saying that you want the table view to start with a specific row selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with (put it in `prepareForSegue:sender:`):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```